# String functions in the jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

So I have a jenkins pipeline which works fine. However I added the following lines of code to the groovy script and the build fails:

```
def gitTemp = env.GIT_URL
def indexOfCom = gitTemp.indexOf('com',0) 
def gitShort = gitTemp.substring(indexOfCom)
```

Comment: Why it fails, what is the exception and it's message?

Comment: We need your log

Comment: so in the pipeline log doesnt say anything explicitly.Thats what the problem i with this thing.It straight away fails.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using substring I used:

```
def gitShort = gitURL1.split('com')[1]
```

which has worked.

Answer (score 0):

This could be because the script by default runs in sandboxed mode. So in the script you are not allowed to use such functions like "substring()","indexOf()" etc. , except a few like split(). You can uncheck the sandbox checkbox below the groovy script text area and then when you run the script it will create a request to allow the script to run . You can then allow the script in the "manage jenkins" menu. Hope it helps.